# Cannot create envelope from given source

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I am trying to consume a SOAP based web service with the class *org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate* of Spring WS 2.2.2 release, like this:

```
webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(uri);
webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(new SOAPMessageSenderWithAuth());
res = (RESPONSE) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
```

The request is built with a class that has been generated from WSDL-files of the web service.

The webservice has been successfully tested with SOAP UI, but when accessing it with Java the Exception "***SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to create envelope from given source (SAAJ0511)***" and "***Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element is not named 'Envelope' (SAAJ0514)***" is thrown.

Does anyone have any advice for this exception?

Thanks in advance!

The Spring bean for *webServiceTemplate* is defined as following:

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate"
    p:marshaller-ref="jaxbMarshaller"
    p:unmarshaller-ref="jaxbMarshaller"
    p:defaultUri="...">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
        <property name="messageSender">
          <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
              <property name="credentials">
                  <bean class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
                      <constructor-arg value="..."/>
                      <constructor-arg value="..."/>
                  </bean>
              </property>
          </bean>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

The Exception is:

org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source

This is the class for the Web Service Client using the Spring WS Template:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
import com.myproject.soap.client.services.SOAPWebServiceClient;

/**
 *
 * @param <REQUEST>
 * @param <RESPONSE>
 */
public class DefaultSOAPWebServiceClient<REQUEST, RESPONSE> implements SOAPWebServiceClient<REQUEST, RESPONSE>
{
    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DefaultSOAPWebServiceClient.class.getName());
    @Resource(name = "webServiceTemplate")
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    @Override
    public RESPONSE sendAndReceive(final REQUEST request, final String uri)
    {
        LOG.info("SOAP URL-" + uri);
        LOG.info("REQUEST-" + request.toString());
        RESPONSE res = null;

        try
        {
            res = (RESPONSE) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(uri, request);
        }
        catch (final WebServiceIOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error("Service with URI: " + uri + " is unreachable");
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

The method *sendAndReceive* is called like this:

```
public MYDATAResponse createCustomer(final MYDATA request)
    {
        return (MYDATAResponse) soapWebServiceClient.sendAndReceive((REQUEST) request, getCreateCustomerURI());
    }
```

Comment: Why are you messing around with properties after the construction of the template. You shouldn't be setting a default uri or message sender after it has been configured. Remove the setting and use the `webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(uri, request)` method instead.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I will adjust that, but the SAAJ0511 and SAAJ0514 Exceptions remain...

Comment: You nowhere mention an exception number so what exception is that...

Comment: It also looks like you are simply sending the wrong object but you aren't showing enough code.

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your help! 
The exception numbers are SAAJ0514 and SAAJ0511. So you think the Object I am trying to send does not match the actual WSDL-Scheme? I will try to generate the class for the request again from the corresponding WSDL-files

Comment: Also why are you setting a custom messageFactory? That shouldn't be needed. Which server are you running on?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the exception while parsing the response from service, try sending the request from soap UI and check if it is working. 
If it is working in soap ui and not here, then you are not getting proper response, that can be because of improper request.
In my case the issue was my endpoint url in code consists of "?wsdl". After removing it worked perfectly fine.